# ListView click then go to other activity with auto data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-activity

I have a project. I do not know what to do or how to start, so any comments will help.

I want to make an Android app with search on top then ListView. Once you clicked on the ListView, it will take you to the other screen with all of the info of a place. Like the Name of the place, weather, and more.

I am thinking, it is easy but I need to make many Activity's to just make every screen of every places. Is there any way to make it simple? Like I will put all the info in a string then it will automatically assign every info to one activity and assign them to every item in the ListView?

Comment: You can use Intent or bundle for sending data into an activity to another activity. Search it on google.

Comment: You can use any of the following: popups, dialogs, fragments

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make every screen for every data just fetch data into var in activity / fragment  from Database and show it on Screen

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZfjWXYm80k&vl=en

Answer (score 0):

Don't make many activities for that. Rather use concept of single activity where you will have single activity across the app and many fragments.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/8i73ic/its_official_google_officially_recommends_single/

Just pass data from one fragment to another.

Comment: for beginners ?

Answer (score 0):

both fragment and activity you can use for show info , but for pass data to it you can use java class(class model)  and implement class from Serializable or Parcelable . so pass class to activity or fragment .